# I added a string of code to my a Wordpress php file and it took down my whole website

Tags: php, wordpress

I am relatively new to programming. Today I was doing some research on how to add a different logo into my header and I put this string of code into my `functions.php` file

```
<img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>" />
```

As soon as I did, my entire website went down and I was even kicked out of my dashboard.

It is giving me an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mysitemyway' not found in /home4/marksla2/public_html/wp-content/themes/infocus/functions.php on line 11

I am using the inFocus theme on my site.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: remove the line of code you added..

Comment: what other answer did you expect?

Comment: I can't. It won't even let me into the dashboard. Otherwise I would have.

Comment: Did you modify the file internally from WordPress's editor in settings or did you modify the file externally?

Comment: You could try using code access using ftp or cpanel to access the individual code files and that way access this page where you added the code mentioned above and try removing it. Still it is strange to see that you are out of dashboard access for making that changes.

Comment: What @CaptainRed has mentioned was bascially what I was getting at. If you have modified the file from WordPress interally you will need to somehow get access to that file externally (SSH/local copy) to modify the broken line and re-upload to fix.

Comment: if you have cpanel or something similar you should be able to navigate to the functions file from the browser.

Comment: I should think `functions.php` is not the right place for this - HTML should just be in your theme afaik. Perhaps it has caused a PHP syntax error?

Comment: It was modified through the editor in settings. I have accessed it through the FTPand it is saying that I have an error on line 11 but is not showing anything.

<?php

/**

 * Sets up the theme by loading the Mysitemyway class & initializing the framework

 * which activates all classes and functions needed for theme's operation.

 *

 **/

# Get theme data.

$theme_data = get_theme_data( TEMPLATEPATH . '/style.css' );



# Initialize the Mysitemyway framework.

Mysitemyway::init(array(

 'theme_name' => $theme_data['Name'],

 'theme_version' => $theme_data['Version']

));



?>

Answer (score 0):

To recover the site and be able to log back in, use FTP to replace the `functions.php` file with a fresh, unedited copy. See [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [FTP Clients « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients). Or use your web host's file manager in your control panel.

It's always a good idea to use an external file editor over FTP (or SSH) to edit files; it's a bad idea to use WordPress's built-in file editor, for one of the reasons you just learned.

And, that line of code is not constructed as a standalone php function for a `functions.php` file; that's why it throws and error killed your site.

It will work in a page template `.php` file - such as `header.php` - as that file is executed as a `php` file with `xhtml`.